# getting crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. when trying to call up a page while offline

Tags: javascript, caching, offline

I'm using service workers for my PWA and I have certain pages that I disable when offline. Such as the register page and the login page. When I'm on my home page, I turn my browser to offline to test the pages. When I click on the register link, It takes me to the fallback page telling the user that this page is not available while offline. But when I click on the login page, I am getting this error:

> crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

I'm not getting any of my console logs to try to debug what the issue is. I know this error message is because I'm offline, but it should be firing my catch when I'm offline but it doesn't. It just shows the crbug issue. Here is my network first function in my sw.js file:

```
const networkFirst = async (request, fallbackURL) => {
    try {
        const netRes = await fetch(request);
           console.log("Network Response URL: ", netRes);

        if (netRes.ok) {

            const cache = await caches.open(dynamicCacheName);
            cache.put(request, netRes.clone());
        }
        return netRes;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", error);

        // This is for the excluded pages
        if (
            request.url.match(/register/) ||
            request.url.match(/login/)
        ) {
            const fallback = await caches.match(fallbackURL);
            return fallback;
        }

        const fallback = await caches.match(fallbackURL);
        const cachedRes = await caches.match(request);

        if (!cachedRes) {
            return fallback;
        }
        else {
            return cachedRes;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting this bug error only on my login page. My page url's:

> http://localhost/testtracker/ <-- Home Page works fine when offline.
> http://localhost/testtracker/register/ <-- Registered Page shows the fall back page when offline
> http://localhost/testtracker/login/ <-- Throws the crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated error with the generic "Your Not Connected" message on the page.

I'm still a novice learning about service workers, caching strategies and javascript so any help would be appreciated. Thank You.